# How to deploy Logic App from Visual Studio Community using powershell command?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I tried different ways to deploy my local logic app from VS Community using powershell but none of them are working.
Any solutions for this?

Comment: Could you share what you tried please ?

Comment: Could you please try this powershell command 
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName <Azure-resource-group-name> -TemplateUri https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/master/quickstarts/microsoft.logic/logic-app-create/azuredeploy.json  

and refer this doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-deploy-azure-resource-manager-templates#powershell ,may it helps.

Answer (score 2):

### Logic App deployment successful from Visual Studio (local) through PowerShell Command

The following command worked for me

```
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName <Azure-resource-group-name> -TemplateUri https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/master/quickstarts/microsoft.logic/logic-app-create/azuredeploy.json
```

and here is the output:

[image]

Here is the process that I followed before running the above command.
**Process Flow:**

I have found that there are 2 ways of deploying logic app through PowerShell i.e., Azure RM Template Commands and AZ Modules Commands
**To work with any of the following commands, we are required to install related package files:**
To deploy using Azure RM Template Commands - Run this code on PowerShell:

`Install-Module -Name AzureRM -AllowClobber`

To deploy using AZ module commands - Run this code on PowerShell:

`Install-Module -Name Az -Scope CurrentUser -Repository PSGallery -Force`

Checkout the following links to play with versions (uninstalling old and installing new), setting up the policies, connecting of Azure Accounts, etc in these:
[Azure RM PowerShell Commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/azurerm/install-azurerm-ps?view=azurermps-6.13.0) and [Azure Az Module PowerShell Commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps?view=azps-6.4.0)

Following is the process of which I have tried deploying the Local Visual Studio Logic App to Azure in PowerShell using Azure RM PowerShell Script commands:

**Before deploying:**

1. Create a Logic App in Visual Studio (File > New Project > Select 'Azure Resource Group' > Logic App)

Your solution will be ready in a few seconds, you will be able to see two `json` files. As you select ***prameters.json*** file you will be able to see `json` schema for logic app deployment.

2. To Connect your logic with your Azure Account, right click on ***LogicApp.json*** and select '**Open with logic app designer**'. If you don't find this option, then install this extension in your project:
   [image]
3. Right click on project and click on ***validate***
   [image]

Select your ***resource group, subscription*** and click on ***edit parameters*** - give custom name to your logic app. Otherwise, it will throw you error of null in logicAppName and shows template is invalid.
[image]

After validation, it shows the template is valid. It can be automatically validate during deployment process also, but it's good way to validate to get rid out of errors.

---

**PowerShell Commands to deploy your logic App from visual studio (local):**

1. Install this [Power Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell?view=powershell-7.1) provided by Microsoft Cloud.
2. Run in *Administrator* Mode > Login with `Connect-AzureRmAccount` command (it takes you to browser and connect with Azure account) > after that it imports your subscription and resource group details in the shell like below:
   [image]
3. Use the following command to deploy your logic app

```
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName "AzureAccountMail" -Templatefile "C:\LogicAppTemplats\template.json" -TemplateParameterFile "C:\LogicAppTemplats\parameters.json"
```

Check this following [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-deploy-azure-resource-manager-templates#powershell) for this command overview.
[image]

Done! Deployment Succeeded.
Now Check out in the azure portal:
[image]

---

**Note:**
Here you can find the ***template file*** and ***parameters.json file*** under your project:
[image]

Make Sure you given your logic app name value here in the ***parameters.json*** file:
[image]

And Provide the logic app name, deployment location values in the ***template.json*** file **(LogicApp.json**)
[image]